# pie chart colors are red and blue on upgrade of jfreechart to 1.0.19 from 0.99

Tags: jfreechart

we are upgrading jfreechart library to remove sun packages that are not working with OpenJDK.

the current version is 0.99 for jfreechart. we are upgrading it to 1.0.19
I have done the necessary changes in our implementation? but I'm not able to change pie chart colors for sections. which are coming as red and blue instead of green and yellow. how we can change this behavior is this default behavior? as shown in image component colors in the description are differing.

[image]

Comment: setSectionPaint resolved the issue. was using setBaseSectionPaint previously

Comment: Also consider a custom `DrawingSupplier`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20DrawingSupplier).